# ASP.NET MVC 3 hangs when I open a new project using VS 2010 SP1 Beta

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC 3 was released on Jan 13, 2011.  I was able to install it on my XP SP3 workstation.  But, when I opened an MVC C# project, VS 2010 hangs.  I have repaired VS 2010 and Framework 4.0 with no luck.  The issue was resolved after uninstalling VS 2010 SP1 Beta.  Does anyone know if ASP.NET MVC 3 works with VS 2010 SP1 Beta?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File a bug with [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/), especially since its BETA, they need to know.